# OpenJPA on WAS7 - random selects incorrectly returning no rows

Tags: openjpa, websphere-7

First time asking a question...Appreciate your kindness :-)

I wrote a web service that uses openjpa 1.2.2 to retrieve results against an oracle 11g database.  I deployed the service to WAS 7.

The service works fine when run one at a time, and it even looks good when run against a single node WAS7 instance.

The problem occurs when I go to a 4 node WAS ND instance.  When load is applied (anywhere from 3-20 requests per second), I find that I'm averaging one request that incorrectly returns an empty result in every 1000 requests.  There are no exceptions in the logs - just an empty result from the findById method.

Could this be a tuning issue, either in JPA or on the database end?  Could it be somewhere else?

Comment: Try turning on OpeJPA SQL trace and make sure the correct SQL is being generated in all cases. openjpa.Log=SQL=trace. By any chance are you sharing EntityManagers across threads?

Comment: I wasn't in this case, but had this issue previously. It's worth mentioning to anyone who happens upon this thread in the future that this could be a potential problem.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my own issue.  There were static calls to SimpleDateFormat that were wreaking havoc on my code.  Moving them into a synchronized block where necessary removed the issue.